# Join raster (.tif) and CSV in R

Tags: raster, r, fields-attributes

I have a  .csv file with several attribute fields. I would like to join this to a raster (.tif) file, using an 'ID' column from the CSV file, so that the raster gets all the attributes from the CSV file.

Here's the R code for reading TIFF and CSV:

```
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
     # Read tif file with values that are long integer type
        tif_arc <- raster("tif_arc.tif")

        #Read csv file that has an attribute 'ID' the value of which = the raster value on the tif file 
        csv_whole <- read_delim("csv_qgis.csv",delim = ",")

    glimpse(csv_whole)
```

Here's what the CSV 
data looks like on running "glimpse()" command:

```
$ FOLIAGE_BIOMASS_PER_HA        <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...

$ BARK_BIOMASS_PER_HA           <dbl> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,...

$ ID                            <dbl> 13453064, 11242315, 11150335,...
```

I know this join can be done in ArcGIS using 'ADD JOIN' tool, using attribute field 'ID' but can this be done in R?

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: Possibly because its lacking detail or focus. Do you know how to read a CSV file into R? Do you know how to read a TIF into R? Once you do, edit this question and show the code that does that, then illustrate how the two relate and the output you want.

Answer (score 2):

Best thing to do with questions here is to make a representative simple example.

Here's a 3x4 raster with some values:

```
r = raster(matrix(c(1,1,1,2,1,3,55,12,3,3,2,1),3,4))
```

Now build a data frame - find the unique ID values:

```
ids = unique(r[])
ids
# [1]  1  2 55  3 12
```

And make a data frame like yours with a couple of data columns:

```
d = data.frame(ID=ids, Z1=runif(length(ids)), Z2=rnorm(length(ids))+100)
d
#   ID        Z1        Z2
# 1  1 0.7529156  99.50632
# 2  2 0.8583983  98.67656
# 3 55 0.3375847  98.56974
# 4  3 0.2880901  98.77999
# 5 12 0.5129960 100.93027
```

Okay now we can answer the question. You can get the values out of the raster and match them to the row ID column with `match`:

```
match(r[],d$ID)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 1 5 2 1 4 4 1
```

Those are row numbers. So we can create a copy of `r` to get a raster of the same form as `r` which we will wipe in a second:

```
Z1 = r
```

and then fill its values by looking up `Z1` in those columns:

```
Z1[] = d$Z1[match(r[],d$ID)]
```

`Z1` now has the values of `d$Z1` that match the value in the raster. Some adjustment may be needed if you have NA values in the raster, but the principle is the same.

Repeat over all columns in `d` that you want to work on, either by naming them if you have a small number of well-known named columns, or by looping over the names and making a stack or list of rasters.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but for substituting raster values, I am able to use subs() command as well, but that works only for similar datatype(integer in this case), as also your method. My original csv has some 190 field attributes many of which are character type, which I would like to have in the raster attribute table as well. Will follow your suggestions for making representative eg. the next time.